# Scala generic function with parsing object

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I need a function like this (sorry I need null)

```
def foo[T](json: JsonElement): T = 
json match {
 case x: JsonObject => gson.fromJson(x, classOf[T])
 case _ => null
}
```

Of course this is can not compile :)

Help please!

**upd**

there are result functions

```
def parseObject[T: ClassTag](jo: JsonObject, gson: Gson, name: String): Option[T] = Option(jo.get(name)).map {
  case x: JsonObject =>
    val cTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    gson.fromJson(x, cTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])

  case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T]
}

def parseArray[T: ClassTag](jo: JsonObject, gson: Gson, name: String): java.util.List[T] = Option(jo.get(name)).map {
  case x: JsonArray =>
    val cTag = implicitly[ClassTag[java.util.List[T]]]
    gson.fromJson(x, cTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[java.util.List[T]]])

  case _ => Collections.emptyList[T]
}.getOrElse(Collections.emptyList[T])
```

They are working well :)

Thanks a lot for everyone!

**p.s.**

last question

Is there are some way to transform this functions to parsePrimitive[T](jo: JsonObject, name: String): Option[T] = ???

```
def parseInteger(jo: JsonObject, name: String): Option[Integer] = Option(jo.get(name)).map {
  case x: JsonPrimitive => x.getAsInt
  case _ => null
}

def parseString(jo: JsonObject, name: String): Option[String] = Option(jo.get(name)).map {
  case x: JsonPrimitive => x.getAsString
  case _ => null
}

def parseBoolean(jo: JsonObject, name: String): Option[java.lang.Boolean] = Option(jo.get(name)).map {
  case x: JsonPrimitive => x.getAsBoolean
  case _ => null
}
```

Comment: where gson comes from? What are JsonElement and JsonObject? Are they from some json library?

Comment: This is gson library from Google. JsonElement can be JsonObject, JsonPrimitive, JsonArray or JsonNull

Comment: Expression of type Null doesn't conform to expected type T.

Comment: @HoTicE edit your question with the information you gave me. Add the imports to the code. Don't expect people are going to get out of their way to answer your question.

Comment: I know - this code is not working. It is to show what I need. I need function that take a JsonElement as parameter and parse an Object of T class from it, or return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (using `Option`):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def foo[T : ClassTag](json: JsonElement): Option[T] = json match {
  case x: JsonObject =>
    val cTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    Some(gson.fromJson(x, cTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]))
  case _ => None
}
```

Note that you will need to know what `T` is when calling the function.

If you really do need the `null`, then you can append `.orNull` when retrieving the result.

If you really, really, really must use `null`, then this ought to work:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def foo[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag](json: JsonElement): T = json match {
  case x: JsonObject =>
    val cTag = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
    gson.fromJson(x, cTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
  case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T] // Required for some odd reason.
}
```

Comment: @HoTicE Sorry for any confusion caused by the multiple edits. I think the above should work for you, but I don't have `gson`, so I can't verify it. Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Good Scala style discourages the use of `null`. Beyond that the compiler restricts what types are null-able. Many primitives cannot be `null` (`Int`, `Boolean`, etc.).

The compiler doesn't know if the type `T` is null-able or not so what you've got is not allowed. If `T` can be context bound to some subset of null-able types this might be possible. (But `Option[T]` would still be better.)